# Amazon aws - s3 bucket not uploading image - It creates only the key

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0 and using `"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~2.0"`

Here is my script to upload the image

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'greenhoppingbucket',
    'Key'        => 'sups',
    'Body'        => Input::file('file'),

));
```

After the execution only the key is uploaded in the s3 bucket

i.e., sups is created bucket but not the image.

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'greenhoppingbucket',
    'Key'        => 'sups',
    'Body'        => File::get((string)Input::file('file')),

));
```

dont forget to add `use File;`

when you do 'Body'        => Input::file('file'), you bassiclly putting the temp path into the body instead of the content of the file.

the `File::get` is simply getting the contents of a file

Comment: Thanks, let me try and convey you soon